# Codeception:WebCurlException Error

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, codeception

I have started Codeception with Selenium Webdriver and i am getting an WebCurlException Error after i run codecept.phar .

Steps:

1.Started the selenium stand alone server jar file from command prompt.
2.Then i have run the following command from command prompt.

php codecept.phar run

3.Then i get the following Error in my console.

"[WebdrivercurlException]
  curl error thrown for http POST to http://xxxx.x.x.x:4444/wd/hub/session with params: {desiredcapabilities":{"browserName":"firefox"}}
Failed connect to "127.0.0.1:4444"; No error"

Please see the attached screenshot below.

[image]

Thanks

Partha

Comment: Check codeception and selenium server compatibility. You may need to use different version of selenium server jar.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because you are not running GhostDriver which enables Selenim do headless testing with frameworks like Codeception. Try this in your command prompt

```
phantomjs --webdriver=4444
```

This will instantiate GhostDriver on `12.0.0.1:4444`. You may then run your tests afterwards.